# Concentration & Wisdom

Tags: wisdom, right-concentration, understanding

Right concentration supports wisdom(panna) if right mindfulness arises? If right mindfulness isn't there then does right concentration support ignorance?

Answer (score 1):

> Right concentration supports wisdom(panna) if right mindfulness arises? If right mindfulness isn't there then does right concentration support ignorance?

Each limb of the N8FP has its opposite counterpart:

> From wrongness comes failure, not success. And how is it, monks, that from wrongness comes failure, not success?

> "In a person of wrong view, wrong resolve comes into being. In a person of wrong resolve, wrong speech. In a person of wrong speech, wrong action. In a person of wrong action, wrong livelihood. In a person of wrong livelihood, wrong effort. In a person of wrong effort, wrong mindfulness. In a person of wrong mindfulness, wrong concentration. In a person of wrong concentration, wrong knowledge. In a person of wrong knowledge, wrong release.

> "This is how from wrongness comes failure, not success. ~~ [AN 10.103](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.103.than.html) ~~

Answer (score 0):

From an10.58, based on Thanissaro & Sujato translations and my interpretation.

```
 Samādhippamukhā sabbe dhammā
```

> Samadhi is the chief over all dhammā, it is presiding over them.

```
 Satādhipateyyā sabbe dhammā.
```

> Mindfulness is their ruler, as it governs them

```
  Paññuttarā sabbe dhammā.
```

> Wisdom is their superior, as it surpasses them

A rightly focused mind always has right mindfulness, it is therefore said to be rightly focused.

Like a good king would have a good government or he wouldn't be a good king.